# Multiple Comma Separated Rows to Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will split this below which is in row 1 into multiple columns. `A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M` but I have a lot of rows to do this to and so far I have only managed to get it to do row 1 while leaving all other rows untouched.

Here is how each row looks before the macro runs. All rows have different data:

```
BB1300TN1,"TRNSDOA2JA","A32LF4MQ122016","003261761195","D12MP-100C- 
R","","AD10920010","0","","","777777",06/20/2018,"kbktqf"
```

And this is what I need all rows to look like after but for all rows:

```
   A            B       C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J   K   L   M
BB1300TN1  TRNSDOA2JA  xxx  xxx  xxx  xxx  xxx  xxx  xxx  xxx xxx xxx xxx
```

Here is the code I'm currently trying to use but like I said it only does row 1 and stops. I need it to keep looping through all rows (usually around 200) and change all.

```
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
 If Sheet.Name = "Data" Then
      Sheet.Delete
 End If
 Next Sheet
 Const strFileName = "C:\Jabil\Jabil.TXT"
  Dim wbkS As Workbook
Dim wshS As Worksheet
Dim wshT As Worksheet
Set wshT = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=1, 
Type:=xlWorksheet)
wshT.Name = "Data"
On Error Resume Next
Set wbkS = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=strFileName)
Set wshS = wbkS.Worksheets(1)
wshS.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wshT.Range("A1")
wbkS.Close SaveChanges:=False
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If
 Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, OtherChar _
    :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4 
    ,1), Array(5, _
    1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), 
    Array(11, 1), Array(12 _
    , 1), Array(13, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
   Cells.Select
  Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Comment: First of all, get rid of that `On Error Resume Next`.  Then remove [those `Select`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/445425).  After that it will be easier for you to debug your code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using text to columns, you can feed each cell value in a array and then use 'split'.
Try the below code. if you have the source data in column A, it would display the results starting from column B in the same sheet.
Later, if you want to get rid of the double quotes, you can always find and replace thru vba.

```
Dim cel As Range
Dim splitarr As Variant
Dim j As Long
Dim str1 As String

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Range("A1:A10") 'change sheet and range as required


For Each cel In rng
  splitarr = Split(cel.Text, ",")
  For j = 0 To UBound(splitarr)
  str1 = splitarr(j)
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Cells(cel.Row, (cel.Column + j + 1)).Value = str1
  Next
Next
```